# How to use one print statement yet still print on multiple lines

Tags: python, string, output

Is there a way I can use only one print statement, yet still  achieve the same effect as is in the code below?  I have attempted end statements to which either one don't work in this situation or, I am using incorrectly:

```
print ('Deposit: ' + str(deposit))
print ('Withdrawl: ' +  str(withdrawl))
print ('Available amount: ' + str((deposit + withdrawl)//1))
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use `\n` to insert a newline:

```
print('Deposit: {}\nWithdrawl: {}\nAvailable amount: {}'.format(
    deposit, withdrawl, (deposit + withdrawl) // 1))
```

It's not necessarily better, though. IMHO using separate `print()` statements here is more readable.

You could make it slightly better with string concatenation:

```
print(('Deposit: {}\n' +
    'Withdrawl: {}\n' +
    'Available amount: {}').format(deposit, withdrawl, (deposit + withdrawl) // 1)
```

Which, again, is not necessarily better IMHO.

I also used [`format`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) to improve readability; this removed the need for manual `str` calls, and is more readable (it can do a lot more, see the link).

> I have attempted end statements to which either one dont work in this situation or, I am using incorrectly

I assume you used something like `print('foo', 'bar', end='\n')`, this won't work, because `end` is only appended to end *end* of all the arguments; the `sep` parameter is printed between the arguments (this defaults to a space).
So what you want to do, is: `print('foo', 'bar', sep='\n')`

The downside of this, is that you will need 3 `.format` calls, or keep your "ugly" string concatenations.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using Python 3.x.  If so, then you can set the [`sep` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) of `print` to `'\n'` in order to have each argument be separated by a newline:

```
print('Deposit: ' + str(deposit), 'Withdrawl: ' +  str(withdrawl), 'Available amount: ' + str((deposit + withdrawl)//1), sep='\n')
```

Although this does make you line pretty long.  You might want to consider breaking it over two lines:

```
print('Deposit: ' + str(deposit), 'Withdrawl: ' +  str(withdrawl),
      'Available amount: ' + str((deposit + withdrawl)//1), sep='\n')
```

---

Note that you could also just drop a few newline characters in select places.  This would allow you to write the above as simply:

```
print('Deposit: ', deposit, '\nWithdrawl: ', withdrawl, '\nAvailable amount: ', (deposit + withdrawl)//1)
```

The nice thing about this solution is that it gets rid of all those calls to `str` (`print` automatically stringifies its arguments).

---

Last but not least, if you are actually using Python 2.x, then you can import the Python 3.x `print` function from [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html).  Place this line at the top of your code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use template rendering like:

```
template = '''Deposit: {0}
Withdrawal: {1}
Available amount: {2}'''

deposit = 1000
withdrawal = 900

print template.format(deposit, withdrawal, (deposit + withdrawal)//1)
```

I however do not get the balance formula, can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this

```
 print(('Deposit: %s\n' +
      'Withdrawl: %s\n' +
      'Available amount: %s') % (deposit, withdrawl, (deposit + withdrawl) // 1)
```